# NullReferenceException when setting a Registry Value

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I am getting a NullReference Exception when I try to set a value to a registry key.  Below is my code.  Does anyone know why?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Current Version\\Policies\\System", true);
            myKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the text it. I am getting that error, and I am having trouble figuring out why. Keep in mind I am new to c#

Comment: Do you get a line number for the error?

Answer (score 4):

Try CreateSubKey instead of OpenSubKey.  The latter will return null if the key does not exist.  It's likely the key does not exist and that is why you hit a null reference on the next line.

Answer (score 3):

Current Version should be one word. I.e. CurrentVersion.

**Edit:** I also agree with Jared you should be using CreateSubKey as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the space between Current Version.

Comment: No, you'll still have a problem if the subkey isn't there. Suggest you take Jareds advice.